# Nginx Help Wordpress Custom Permalink Rewrite

Tags: wordpress, nginx, url-rewriting, permalinks

Nginx Help Wordpress Custom Permalink Rewrite problem.

Test site : http://unknown/blog/
Post link : http://unknown/blog/archives/2604.html(404 error)

My permalink settings is '/archives/%post_id%.html'

index.php?$args . args is not '.html' recognition.

```
  location /blog/ {
     try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;
}
```

$args
is possible '/archives/%post_id%'
is not possible '/archives/%post_id%.html'

my all posting link is '.html' i need help !

Answer (score 0):

Another method
 set permalink '/archives/%post_id%'

user connect in post 'http://unknown/blog/archives/2604.html' (search in google)
                 redirect ->  'http://unknown/blog/archives/2604'

possible?

Answer (score 0):

Oh my god. 
this problem is solved.

my mistake.

im used the Caching

```
location ~* \.(html|htm|txt)$ {
    #add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
    access_log off;
    expires 1d;
    break;
    }
```